# Color for drop location in JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

When you drag and drop something (internally) in a JList there is a small selection that encompass the drop location(marks the point where you will drop the selection).

How can that selection be modified, especially the color of it - which sometimes is very hard to noticed if you changed the background of the JList.

Comment: Could you please include a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of waht have you tried? Just a shot in the dark: what about modifying `List.dropLineColor` property in the UIManager? `UIManager.put("List.dropLineColor", Color.RED)`

Comment: You shot well. It worked and that what I was interested into. It's a pity that is not something customizable as CellRenderer .

Comment: Well, you are welcome then :D It is indeed but maybe it's a design decision to keep this feature related to the look and feel unified across the whole application.